How to get rid of StaleElementReferenceException and NoSuchElement exception while automating amazon website using selenium Java
I was practicing Selenium using the Amazon website and frequently encountered StaleElementReferenceException and NoSuchElementException errors. Here's the automation process I followed:
Open the Amazon website and search using the search bar.
Search for the required item using a for loop.
If the required item is not available, navigate to the next page using the pagination button.
The problem occurs every time I reach page 2, where it throws a StaleElementReferenceException. I tried surrounding the code with a try/catch block, but it resulted in a NoSuchElementException. The item I am searching for is on page 6, and I am unable to reach it. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?
package Daszio.AmazonPurchase;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Practice {
    @Test
    public void addCart() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("shoes for men", Keys.ENTER);
        List<WebElement> requiredItem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-cy='title-recipe']/h2/a/span"));

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredItem.size(); i++) {
            
            if(!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-cy='title-recipe']/h2/a/span")).isEnabled()) {
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-cy='title-recipe']/h2/a/span"))));
            }
            if (requiredItem.get(i).getText()
                    .contains("Mens Solid Lace Up Genuine Leather Formal Brogue Shoes (201826FW)")) {
                requiredItem.get(i).click();
                break;
            } else {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-cel-widget,'search')]/div/div/span/a[1]"))));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-cel-widget,'search')]/div/div/span/a[1]")).click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-cy='title-recipe']/h2/a/span"))));
                //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-cy='title-recipe']/h2/a/span"))));

            }
        }
    }
}

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.10.2
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
FAILED: Daszio.AmazonPurchase.Practice.addCart
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
  (Session info: chrome=127.0.6533.120)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Build info: version: '4.23.1', revision: '656257d8e9'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.3'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [d7c9eae23de15df5934510271a594a31, getElementText {id=f.95A4236C3E7E65FD6546416CB175C054.d.7939BAA24D78E3FC3E3C4703CDF1B6BD.e.328}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 127.0.6533.120, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 127.0.6533.119 (bdef6783a05..., userDataDir: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Loca...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51720}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:51720/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 127.0.6533.120, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on windows (d7c9eae23de15df5934510271a594a31)] -> xpath: //div[@data-cy='title-recipe']/h2/a/span]
Session ID: d7c9eae23de15df5934510271a594a31
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:191)
    at Daszio.AmazonPurchase.Practice.addCart(Practice.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:141)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:686)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:230)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:992)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:203)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:154)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:134)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:739)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:614)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:421)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:413)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:373)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1274)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1112)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1079)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:293)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:91)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================




once you click your webelement reference array will become stale.  (because the DOM updates after you click the pagination button)  You might also want a sleep before using driver.findElements just to be sure the initial DOM has fully populated before iterating the webelement reference array.  (or catch Stale Element exceptions and re-get the array when caught)  I would also axe the implicit wait... (that is global and only needs to be set once, but you shouldn't mix implicit and explicit waits... explicit waits with Expected Conditions are always the better way to go...)

Hi, thanks for you reply. I have actually figured out the problem.
In the code I have declared requiredItem WebElement outside the for loop. Due to this when I traverse to other pages the requiredItem WebElement does not fetch the items from the current DOM as the previous page DOM as been stored. This is the reason for that exception.
